# Moving large numbers of files and directories to a different directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename, recursive

I'm trying to move the following move a large number of files that exist in the following structure to a /mnt/originals but I need to maintain the structure at the same time. I know cp would be a solution but can't use cp because of space limitations.

```
/mnt/originals-us/4
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b8
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b4
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b3
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9/a62/
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9/a47/
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9/f0f/
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9/a62/aa5/file16.png
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9/a62/ba1/file1.png
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9/a47/31f/file3.mov
/mnt/originals.us/4/0b9/f0f/
.
.
.
```

Etc. It is a pretty large set of files of different file names and types. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
mv /mnt/originals-us/ /mnt/originals/
```

but get the following

```
mv: inter-device move failed: `/mnt/originals-us/10/0b9/' to `/mnt/originals/10/0b9'; unable to remove target: Is a directory
```

I also thought about writing a massively chanin-ed command but I don't think that would work either.

This is what I have so far.

```
find . -type f -print | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev
```

This obviously gives me all the filenames but how do I chain it with the first part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use rsync with `--remove-source-files`

```
rsync -vr --remove-source-files /mnt/originals-us/ /mnt/originals/
```

Potential caveat:  I do not know how rsync checks for space before performing potentially damaging actions.  In a perfect world, rsync would calculate how much space is needed, check to see if that is available, then abort and warn the user or (if the space is adequate) perform the operation.

EDIT:  I omitted the recursion option (`-r`) by mistake, thanks to the OP for mentioning, now fixed

Comment: Worked perfectly after I added  -r so it should be       rsync -v -r --remove-source-files /mnt/originals-us/ /mnt/originals/

Comment: @MarkD I recommend `-a` (preserve everything), which includes `-r` as well as preservation of permissions, timestamps, special files, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `rsync` solution is a lot more efficient but it is possible with `find`, too. The worst case: one process per file:

```
find ... -exec cp --parents {} /dest/path \; -delete
```

`find` would delete the source file after successful copy only.

But we can start a project "fun with find" for optimization (remove the `echo`s and the `\` before the `|` after testing):

```
find ... -type d -exec echo mkdir /target/{} \; -exec bash -c \
  'echo find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 \| '\
  'xargs -0 mv --target-directory=/target/{}' \;
```

In the typical case: 5 processes per directory.

With your example (few files per directory) it may make sense to make a `-print0 | xargs -0 mkdir` in the target root first (and take the `mkdir` out of the main `find` call).

Comment: I *really* like the solution but you're right rsync was more efficient.